# Undefined index: joinColumns doctrine + symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following structure of Entities in my project.

```
class MyEntity
{
 [... some more fields...]
 /**
 * @Type("array<string, string>")
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Me\MyBundle\Entity\Example")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="example_myentity",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="plan_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="example", referencedColumnName="label")}
 * )
 */
private $example;
}



class Example
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=50, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
private $label;
}
```

When i tried to get "$example" using the findby() function from Doctrine i got the following  notice:

> Undefined index: joinColumns

I tried to debug it, and the problem seems to be in the doctrine file BasicEntityPersister.php in the function

```
 _getSelectEntitiesSQL($criteria, $assoc = null, $lockMode = 0, $limit = null, $offset = null, array $orderBy = null),
```

I observed in the stack trace that **the second parameter "$assoc" is always null**, and I think it's why Doctrine doesn't make the JOIN statement.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update the database ?

Comment: Yes, it's all up-to-date. Database updated, cache cleared...

Comment: If it's many to many then shouldn't MyEntity.$example be $examples?  Are you initializing it as a doctrine array in the constructor? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Yes i'm initializing it as a doctrine array in the constructor, when i get the list of MyEntity for example i get all the parameters without problems, the problem is when i try to filter it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is a bug, possibly [this one](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3559).

I have the same problem, and the only solution for now seems to be to wait for an update for the BasicEntityPersister or write your query which is pretty straight forward.

First add a repository to your class

```
/**
 * MyClass
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\MyClassRepository")
 */
class MyClass
...
```

Then in your repositoryclass:

```
class MyClassRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByExample( Example $example )
    {
         return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('m')
                ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:MyClass', 'm')
                ->innerJoin('m.examples', 'e')
                ->where('e.id = :exampleid' )
                ->setParameter('exampleid', $example->getId() )
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Then finally you can get all the MyClass instances related to an Example by:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:MyClass')->findByExample( $example );
```

Comment: I too believe it is a bug, i have created the following bug report: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2988

Which also contains a patch that fixes the issue.

Comment: Link to the bug is dead